# Issue with using polymorphic_path with FactoryGirl build object

Tags: factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am using factory_girl and rspec2 for my testing. I have an issue with the following code:

```
let(:book) { build(:book, id: 1) }
book_path(book)
```

book_path statement is generating **/books** url instead of **/books/1**. I can use create, but any suggestions on how to fix this using build strategy?

I am using

```
rspec-rails (2.11.0)
factory_girl (3.5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `book.to_param` (that's actually what `book_path(book)` is doing under the hood) and see what it returns. By default `to_param` returns `id`, but your book is not saved yet, so it can return nil.

Comment: In my case book is not saved, but I assigned an ID. When I do to_param, it is returning the id, but when I do book_path looks like it is behaving differently.